# Reread file after fseek to beginning?

Tags: c, stdio, libc

I have this test program:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
   FILE* read;
   FILE* write;

   write = fopen("file.txt", "w");

   fwrite("Hallo", 1, 6, write);
   fflush(write);

   read = fopen("file.txt", "r");
   //--------------------------------------
   // setbuf(read, NULL); // read unbuffered
   //--------------------------------------
   char buf[6];
   fread(buf, 1, 6, read);
   printf("Should be -Hallo-: %s\n", buf);

   fseek(write, 0, SEEK_SET);
   fwrite("Welt", 1, 4, write);
   fflush(write);

   fseek(read, 0, SEEK_SET);    
   fread(buf, 1, 6, read);
   printf("Should be -Welto-: %s\n", buf);

   fclose(read);
   fclose(write);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Ysn4cs

It writes "Hallo" to a file, then reads "Hallo". Then we seek to the beginning and overwrite the file with "Welt". This should result the next read (also seek to the beginning) to read "Welt**o**", the "o" is a leftover of "Hall**o**".

This code works on Linux and Windows but not on VxWorks (second fread() give "Hallo" again). It works on all 3 OSes, when I

- set read to unbuffered (see comments)
- reopen read before the second fread().

I read the documentation on fseek(), and I think, this is no bug, but really undefined behavior. It is not defined whether the OS must reread the file or if it can keep the buffer.

I am not a native English speaker (maybe I misunderstood something) so I am asking you if this is true.
Also, is there another solution to the two above? I would like to keep buffered reading and don`t want the overhead of reopening. Is there a function to reset the buffer once?

Comment: Your analysis is [probably] correct. It may be a VxWorks bug (i.e. it does _not_ reread on `fseek`). VxWorks' POSIX compliance has been spotty. But, what you're doing is suspect. Doing `fwrite`, `fseek(0)`, `fwrite` has an issue because the file stream does _not_ get truncated. You realize that because after writing `"Welt"`, you _do_ expect to see the `"o"` from the first `fwrite`. But, this is doing things the hard way. And, to what end? The usual is to _not_ `fseek` and just have both work sequentially. It almost looks like you're trying to do a pipe. So, what do you _really_ want to do?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to simulate what _two_ processes might do to communicate some sort of state. If that's what you're really trying to do, you have a race condition because the writer would probably overwrite the first write with the second _before_ the reader could see/read the first. If you're _not_ trying to use two processes, why not use a _single_ stream, opened with `"w+"` or `"r+"`. But, then, why?

Comment: What I really want is: 1 process periodically writes the file with a small binary content (OK/NOK). Another process reads it. The reader does not see any changes, because it is stuck on buffer. I dumbed it down to the strange behaviour i saw. (Yes, I lied a little bit, bufferless read is sufficient, I am just curious if there are other solutions).
Appending the file is not the solution here!

Comment: _small binary content_ seems like a message protocol to me. Using `read/write` [vs. `fread/fwrite`] is probably better. Opening a named pipe (e.g. `mkpipe`) or `AF_UNIX` socket might help. But, what I've used [for R/T commercial mission critical SW] in the past was SysV IPC. `msgget/msgsnd/msgrcv`

Comment: There are million other solutions, but the file interface is what we use for best compatibility (different OSes and containers) and debugging. This is not for debate here. I just want to verify what I found out about fseek!

Comment: You _did_ ask for other solutions. And, you're okay with "bufferless", so, [as I mentioned] just use `read/write`. It's _more_ portable [and better] for your intended use case [re. the issue with `fread/fwrite` on VxWorks]. Since this is a message passing impl., hopefully, you've wrapped it in a layer (e.g. `mymsg_*`), which should make the changes easy. Or, write your own `FILE` impl. Even with all that, you've got a race condition. Otherwise, I think you have an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem